# Long paths in the supercritical percolation.

Tags: pr.probability, open-problems, percolation

I have a question on the length of the longest path, denoted by $\ell_n$, in the supercritical percolation on $[0,n]^d$, denoted by $C_n$.
We know that $C_n$ has a giant component whose size is of order $n^d$. The question is that what is the order of $\ell_n$. Is it $n^d$?

For $d=2$, Grimmett proved that $\ell_n$ is of order $n^2$. The idea is interesting. He showed that there are many (of order $n$) edge-disjoint paths crossing the square from the left side to the right side. Then near the left and right sides, we can find crossings from the bottom to the top. By geometry property of the dimension 2, the two crossings cut all above  edge-disjoint paths. Hence we get a long path whose size is of order $n^2$.

For $d\geq 3$, it is shown that there are many (of order $n^{d-1}$) edge-disjoint paths crossing the square from the left side to the right side. However, I can not glue these paths.

Do you have any idea to deal with my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you were in the supercritical regime of the 2d percolation, you could perhaps use induction.  Say, for $d=3$, you would know that each plane parallel to the $xy$-plane has a path of length ${\sim} n^2$.  Then, perhaps, you would be able to use one such a path on the bottom plane and another on the top plane to glue your ${\sim} n^{d-1}$ edge-disjoint paths from top plane to the bottom ...

Comment: I'm not sure about the induction. For example when $d=3$, if $p_c(Z^2) >p> p_c(Z^3)$, then a.s. there is no path of length $\sim n^2$ in any plane. And in fact, I'm interested in the case $d=3$.

Comment: You are right.  My suggestion could only work if $p>p_{\mathrm{c}}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ (which is what I said in the first sentence of my previous comment).  Can you already handle this case?

Comment: No, i'am sorry. In fact, it is possible that the long path in a plane does not cut all (or positive proportion of) the edge-disjoint paths. We know that they are all in the largest component (a.s. all the paths of length larger than $C \log n$ are in this component). But it is not good enough to glue them by a self-avoiding path.